# Sum all the rows in sql after i select a start and end date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I select a start and end date, and after that, i would like to sum all the orders.

If we take a look at my image, the sum value will be 80. From 2017-09-02 to 2017-09-10, there was 80 order.

And i want to echo that sum value with php.

My sql code:

```
$sql = "
                        SELECT datum, COUNT(rendeles_id) AS ennyi FROM rendeles_adatok 

                            WHERE datum >= '$date_start' AND (datum <= '$date_end' AND status = $rendeles_allapot)

                        GROUP BY datum ORDER BY $kereses_sorrend
                   ";
```

The "ennyi" alias is that i echo out in the Orders on that day column. (last column on the photo)

[image]

Comment: What's your question? What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the overall total, remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(rendeles_id) AS ennyi
FROM rendeles_adatok 
WHERE datum >= '$date_start' AND
      datum <= '$date_end' AND
      status = $rendeles_allapot;
```

If you want a total row in addition to the other data, use [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT datum, COUNT(rendeles_id) AS ennyi
FROM rendeles_adatok 
WHERE datum >= '$date_start' AND
      datum <= '$date_end' AND
      status = $rendeles_allapot
GROUP BY datum WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: And what should i echo out? What is storeing the total sum? (The counted row is the 'ennyi'.)

Comment: @Parkolo11 . . . In the first query, `ennyi` has the total sum.

Comment: Yes, for each days, and not the all.

Comment: I added a new photo in my first post.